# Sending emails with postfix via port 587 on gmail

Tags: unix, postfix

Since my ISP blocks port 25 I'd like to be able to configure postfix to send smtp email over port 587. Every time I try to send an email I see this in the mail.log

```
Oct 17 10:37:49 new-host-2 postfix/smtp[1552]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.113.27]:25: Operation timed out
```

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that this doesn't work over port 25. What do I need to modify in order to get smtp to communicate over port 587? I tried using port forwarding but that wasn't working either.

Not sure but I think if I can get the mail.log to show `[74.125.113.27]:587` this would work. Any idea how to switch this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your ISP is blocking you from connecting to other sites port 25.  You would somehow have to get every mail server that you want to connect to to *listen* on port 587.  Good luck with that.

Comment: I only need to connect to one mail server (google) that listens on 587. I just need to know how to switch over to that port.

Comment: I don't see any reason why an ISP should block port 25 specifically. But as far as Gmail goes, their SMTP server listens on port 587 and that is why you get a timeout on port 25.

Comment: Meher- Exactly! So how do I switch to port 587?

Comment: Gmail’s servers that receive mail from the outside world do *not* listen on port 587. Only their *outgoing* servers, for authenticated Gmail users, listen on 587. Are you trying to use Gmail as our outbound SMTP server, or are you trying to send mail to a Gmail user?

Comment: I'm trying to use Gmail as an outbound SMTP server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most mail servers do not listen on port 587. Those that do, usually designate that as a port for authenticated users only, to relay mail. They generally do not accept incoming e-mail from the outside world on port 587.

**Edit:** It seems like you are trying to use Gmail as an outbound SMTP server. In this case you need to:

1. Connect to `smtp.gmail.com`, not the `aspmx.*` servers, which are for inbound mail.
2. Tell Postfix to connect to the outbound server on port 587 using TLS encryption.
3. Tell Postfix to `AUTH` (authenticate) the connection using your Gmail username and password.

**Edit #2:** Here is an all-in-one example: http://www.bamweb.nl/computer/linux/271

Other documentation:

- [Set up TLS](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html)
- To set the outbound host: `relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587`
- [How to do SMTP AUTH on outbound connections](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html)

Comment: Right. In google's case, the server does listen on 587. I just need to know how to switch ports in postfix.

Comment: `aspmx.l.google.com` does not listen on port 587. Maybe you are thinking of `smtp.gmail.com`?

Comment: you're right ... I'm thinking of smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Thanks Nate. I'll take a swing at this. Also, this may sound strange but how do I switch the server I'm connecting to? Is there some sort of configuration file for postfix? I can't seem to find how it's choosing to connect to google's server. Strange I know but I must've somehow set this somewhere.

Comment: I’ve added a note about the `relayhost` parameter.

Comment: Boom. You're the man Nate.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to send mail on port 587, the server on the *other end* needs to be listening on port 587, which it probably isn't.

If your provider blocks outgoing port 25 (and many residential ISPs do; those that don't should, it's simply a good practice) then you will need to configure Postfix to send all outgoing mail to your ISP's mail server for delivery.

In most cases, you can set the following in your postfix `main.cf` to relay all mail to your ISP's mail server:

```
relayhost = mail.your-isp.com
```

See also the [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost) documentation.